# how do i start learning jquery with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

pls recommend good resources/books to start learning jquery with asp.net

Comment: i think i go with the jquery in action book

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need books. There are so many good tutorials on the web.

First you should start by reading the info at jQuery.com. Start with "[Getting started with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works)".
Then you can have a look at other tutorials. Here are some good ones:
- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started)
- [Learninig jQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/)
- [www.webdesignerwall.com](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers/)

jQuery is platform independent. So it doesn't matter if you are coding in PHP or .NET.

Comment: but still books helps a lot than tutorials.

Comment: How? I never read a book to learn jQuery. I only read the online tutorials and looks at other examples. Learning by doing is the most efficient way of learning. Just read the tutorial at jQuery's own website, and give it a go. It's very simple.

Comment: Well a goog book isn't hurting anybody. I read "jQuery in Action" when I was two weeks away in my holidays and hadn't access to the internet. Helped me to fill some gaps and learned things I probably wouldn't have discovered by only reading tutorials. You discover stuff you wouldn't have searched for but can be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently reading [jQuery In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355) and I find it easy to read with great examples.

There are other questions on SO that provide many other resources.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881002/jquery-resources
[jQuery & ASP.Net Resources & Gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241550/jquery-asp-net-resources-gotchas)

Comment: hi RC, i want to give u +1 for help but can't as it says "vote up requires 15 reputation" :(

Comment: You should have enough reputation to upvote him by now. :)

Answer (score 4):

Tekpub has a great JQuery series.
http://tekpub.com/preview/jquery

Answer (score 1):

If you also need to learn Java Script (not just JQuery), then check out the Head First series of books.  The Java Script book is awesome.

http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjs/

Answer (score 0):

The jquery tutorial here is helpful for learing how to manipulate DOM elements using jQuery, but the ajax section of the tutorial assumes you are using PHP:

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Here are several free resources for using jquery for ajax with asp.net:

http://www.misfitgeek.com/2011/05/calling-web-service-page-methods-with-jquery/

http://www.seoasp.net/post/2008/07/16/jQuery-To-Call-ASPNET-Page-Methods-and-Web-Services.aspx

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/